# 都 inside 她的吃穿用度，都和别人不一样。

Tags: grammar, emphasis

> 她的吃穿用度，都和别人不一样。

**My translation** : *Expenses which she spends for foods and attires/clothes are different from others.*

I guess that 都 which is used inside the original sentence functions as emphasizing that the girl/women is totally different from others. So I think that applying "every" or "all" (compared to other persons) to 都 here makes sense.

Concretely, I think that 都 here is linked to persons rather than the way she spends.

Is this my thought correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 她的吃穿用度，都和别人不一样。

Here, 都 means "**all** of the above - her eating, dressing, and spending habits."

- Her eating, dressing, and spending, all are different from the others.

Answer (score 1):

Your translation : Expenses which she spends for foods and attires/clothes are different from others.

Your understanding is correct about the 都. So I would modify your original translation to:

Her expenses of foods and attires/clothes are **totally** different from those of others.